# Use Node JS module in HANA trial account

Tags: java, node.js, hana, sap-web-ide, hana-xs

How to enable **node js module** for HANA XSA in HCP?

BTW, It is not under

> ***Tools --> Preferences --> Feature*** where in I enabled JAVA development.

[image: Missing Node JS Module in HANA trial]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hey ! Got to know that Node Module is present as On Premise feature. It has not been released on cloud yet. Though Node module feature is in Beta phase on Cloud. So, it will be released soon.

Comment: Finally, I found the solution to try out [NodeJS on HANA using GCP](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hxe-gcp-getting-started-launcher-xsa.html)

Comment: @Manjunath that's the XSA edition though. If you want to go cloud, I think the option is cloud foundry

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use node js module in their follow these steps:

Step 1: Go to Preferences means setting icon

Step 2: Enable Tools for node js Development(On).

Step 3: Refresh page

Step 4: Then go to your above steps you will get node js module.